# Processing millions of records using asyncio causes memory error

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

> I get the below error

> Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from MemoryErrors while normalizing exceptions.
> Current thread 0x0000ffff88de5010 (most recent call first):
> File "test.py", line 173 in wrap_get_fuzzy_match
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88 in _run
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786 in _run_once
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541 in run_forever
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 574 in run_until_complete
> File "test.py", line 224 in 
> Aborted

```
async def get_valuation(url, params, api_header, session, semaphore):
        async with semaphore:
            async with session.get(url, headers=api_header) as response:
                status_code = response.status
                try:
                    if status_code != 200:
                        mmr = {params: 'not found' + ',' + ' ' + str(status_code)}
                    else:
                        asynch_response = await response.json()
                        mmr = await get_best_match(params, asynch_response, str(status_code))
                    return mmr
                except Exception as ex:
                    LOGGER.error(f"Error in get valuation and error was {ex}")
                    return ex


async def wrap_get_fuzzy_match(func, *args, **kwargs):
       try:
           return await func(*args, **kwargs)
       except Exception as err:
           LOGGER.error(f"Error in wrap_get_fuzzy_match and error was {err}")
           return err

async def main(headers, file):
        tasks = []
        sema = asyncio.Semaphore(500)
        BATCH_SIZE = 1000000
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            with open(file) as f:
                while True:
                    batch = [line.strip('\n') for line in islice(f, BATCH_SIZE)]
                    if not batch:
                        break
                    for param in batch:
                        task = asyncio.ensure_future(wrap_get_fuzzy_match(
                            get_valuation,
                            url= API + param,
                            params=param,
                            api_header=headers,
                            session=session,
                            semaphore=sema,
                        ))
                        tasks.append(task)
            responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            return responses
```

Comment: Your batching mechanism isn't doing anything.  You collect a million lines, create a million tasks, and then loop again until you have made one task for every line in the file, as quickly as possible.  Each task eventually returns a json object of unknown size, and all of that data gets collected by gather into one huge list.  So you are trying to hold simultaneously in memory an unknown number of data structures (possibly many millions), each of unknown size.  It's not surprising that you run out of memory.

Comment: Your Python implementation is inefficient in memory usage here & has nothing to do with AWS - you can easily bump up your instance but I would suggest making it more efficient (I'm not sure how but others can shine a light on that). I'll remove the AWS-related tags as this is not related to AWS at all.

Comment: @PaulCornelius: Indenting `responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` into the `while` loop and changing it to `responses.extend(await asyncio.gather(*tasks))` (with a `responses = []` outside the loop), and adding `tasks = []` after you've `gather`-ed them all might help there; you'd still store all the results, but only schedule/store a million tasks at once as intended.

Comment: Well presumably there is some sort of point to the program, such as analyzing the data or writing it to a file or something.  Collecting a million tasks and then letting them get garbage collected before collecting the next million seems like a lot of trouble for nothing.  The correct solution to the memory issue must depend on knowing what the program is FOR, which we don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by passing data in chunks and calling the main function in the loop.

```
async def get_valuation(url, params, api_header, session, semaphore):
    """
    Call fuzzy match api
    :param url:
    :param api_header:
    :param session:
    :param semaphore:
    :return:
    """
    async with semaphore:
        async with session.get(url, headers=api_header) as response:
            status_code = response.status

            try:
                if status_code != 200:
                    mmr = {params: 'not found' + ',' + ' ' + str(status_code)}
                else:
                    asynch_response = await response.json()
                    mmr = await get_best_match(params, asynch_response, str(status_code))
                return mmr
            except Exception as ex:
                LOGGER.error(f"Error in get valuation and error was {ex}")
                return ex


async def wrap_get_fuzzy_match(func, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return await func(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as err:
        LOGGER.error(f"Error in wrap_get_fuzzy_match and error was {err}")
        return err


async def main(params, headers):
    tasks = []
    sema = asyncio.Semaphore(100)
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with timeout(None):
            LOGGER.info(f"Number of urls to process: {len(tasks)}")
            for param in params:
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(wrap_get_fuzzy_match(
                    get_valuation,
                    url=API,
                    params=param,
                    api_header=headers,
                    session=session,
                    semaphore=sema,
                ))
                tasks.append(task)
            responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            return responses


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LOGGER.info("Start Processing")
    BATCH_SIZE = <size of each batch>
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        with open(INPUT) as file:
            inputs = file.readlines()
    except IOError:
        LOGGER.exception("Unable to read valuation input file")
        raise
    chunked_list = list(divide_chunks(big_list=inputs, chunk_size=BATCH_SIZE))
    LOGGER.info(
        f"Chunked size- {len(chunked_list)}"
    )
    batch_counter = 0
    for params in chunked_list:
        batch_counter += 1
        LOGGER.info(
            f"Starting batch number [{batch_counter}] out of [{len(chunked_list)}] "
        )
        results = loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.ensure_future(
                main(params= params,headers=hdr)
            )
        )
        
    LOGGER.info("Processing Completed!!")
    loop.close()
```